# How to upload to physical path using FileUpload control (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to upload to physical path on windows server using FileUpload control. I have 2 websites on the same server and I want to upload image from one site and save it on image folder on the other website.

am using this code now which accept virtual path only

```
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/") & filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx) method will accept a full path to any directory on the server. The trick is ensuring the ASP.Net application has write access to that directory. We usually do this by setting the application pool identity to network service and then grant the Network Service user write access to the file.

Another potential consideration is whether or not you are using impersonation; if you are, the user(s) that you are impersonating will need access to the directory. For example, we impersonate a domain service account for all incoming requests due to the need to access resources on other machines. It is this domain service account that is required to have access to the directory since ASP.Net is performing the operations as that user.